# jsPDF: Converting Html to PDF, jsPDF PubSub Error

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

Im having using the library jsPDF. Im attempting to convert an entire webpage, to a pdf using their beta HTML -> pdf support, but im running into errors.

My code looks like the following, excuse the jade(pug)

```
script(src="/js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js")
script(src="/js/htmlcanvas.min.js")
script(src="/js/jspdf.min.js")
script(src="/js/from_html.min.js")
script(src="/js/addhtml.min.js")
script(src="/js/cell.min.js")


window.onload = function(){
  var doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.fromHTML($('#letter')[0], 15, 15, {
     'width': 170
  }, function(){
      doc.save();
  });   
 }
```

With this code I am running across the following error.

```
jsPDF PubSub Error
```